# CSS: Acceder a los estilos de un vídeo de YouTube embebido

Tags: css

Recientemente, Youtube ha añadido a los vídeos embebidos un enlace que permite verlos directamente en su página web (en la de YouTube):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si le echamos un ojo desde la consola, vemos que se corresponde con la siguiente estructura HTML:

```
<a class="ytp-impression-link" aria-label="Ver en YouTube" target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=afeAUndotas&amp;feature=emb_imp_woyt" data-layer="7">
  <div class="ytp-impression-link-content" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="ytp-impression-link-text">Ver en</div>
    <div class="ytp-impression-link-logo">
      <svg height="100%" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 110 26" width="100%">
        <use class="ytp-svg-shadow" xlink:href="#ytp-id-30"></use>
        <path class="ytp-svg-fill" d="M 16.68,.99 C 13.55,1.03 7.02,1.16 4.99,1.68 c -1.49,.4 -2.59,1.6 -2.99,3 -0.69,2.7 -0.68,8.31 -0.68,8.31 0,0 -0.01,5.61 .68,8.31 .39,1.5 1.59,2.6 2.99,3 2.69,.7 13.40,.68 13.40,.68 0,0 10.70,.01 13.40,-0.68 1.5,-0.4 2.59,-1.6 2.99,-3 .69,-2.7 .68,-8.31 .68,-8.31 0,0 .11,-5.61 -0.68,-8.31 -0.4,-1.5 -1.59,-2.6 -2.99,-3 C 29.11,.98 18.40,.99 18.40,.99 c 0,0 -0.67,-0.01 -1.71,0 z m 72.21,.90 0,21.28 2.78,0 .31,-1.37 .09,0 c .3,.5 .71,.88 1.21,1.18 .5,.3 1.08,.40 1.68,.40 1.1,0 1.99,-0.49 2.49,-1.59 .5,-1.1 .81,-2.70 .81,-4.90 l 0,-2.40 c 0,-1.6 -0.11,-2.90 -0.31,-3.90 -0.2,-0.89 -0.5,-1.59 -1,-2.09 -0.5,-0.4 -1.10,-0.59 -1.90,-0.59 -0.59,0 -1.18,.19 -1.68,.49 -0.49,.3 -1.01,.80 -1.21,1.40 l 0,-7.90 -3.28,0 z m -49.99,.78 3.90,13.90 .18,6.71 3.31,0 0,-6.71 3.87,-13.90 -3.37,0 -1.40,6.31 c -0.4,1.89 -0.71,3.19 -0.81,3.99 l -0.09,0 c -0.2,-1.1 -0.51,-2.4 -0.81,-3.99 l -1.37,-6.31 -3.40,0 z m 29.59,0 0,2.71 3.40,0 0,17.90 3.28,0 0,-17.90 3.40,0 c 0,0 .00,-2.71 -0.09,-2.71 l -9.99,0 z m -53.49,5.12 8.90,5.18 -8.90,5.09 0,-10.28 z m 89.40,.09 c -1.7,0 -2.89,.59 -3.59,1.59 -0.69,.99 -0.99,2.60 -0.99,4.90 l 0,2.59 c 0,2.2 .30,3.90 .99,4.90 .7,1.1 1.8,1.59 3.5,1.59 1.4,0 2.38,-0.3 3.18,-1 .7,-0.7 1.09,-1.69 1.09,-3.09 l 0,-0.5 -2.90,-0.21 c 0,1 -0.08,1.6 -0.28,2 -0.1,.4 -0.5,.62 -1,.62 -0.3,0 -0.61,-0.11 -0.81,-0.31 -0.2,-0.3 -0.30,-0.59 -0.40,-1.09 -0.1,-0.5 -0.09,-1.21 -0.09,-2.21 l 0,-0.78 5.71,-0.09 0,-2.62 c 0,-1.6 -0.10,-2.78 -0.40,-3.68 -0.2,-0.89 -0.71,-1.59 -1.31,-1.99 -0.7,-0.4 -1.48,-0.59 -2.68,-0.59 z m -50.49,.09 c -1.09,0 -2.01,.18 -2.71,.68 -0.7,.4 -1.2,1.12 -1.49,2.12 -0.3,1 -0.5,2.27 -0.5,3.87 l 0,2.21 c 0,1.5 .10,2.78 .40,3.78 .2,.9 .70,1.62 1.40,2.12 .69,.5 1.71,.68 2.81,.78 1.19,0 2.08,-0.28 2.78,-0.68 .69,-0.4 1.09,-1.09 1.49,-2.09 .39,-1 .49,-2.30 .49,-3.90 l 0,-2.21 c 0,-1.6 -0.2,-2.87 -0.49,-3.87 -0.3,-0.89 -0.8,-1.62 -1.49,-2.12 -0.7,-0.5 -1.58,-0.68 -2.68,-0.68 z m 12.18,.09 0,11.90 c -0.1,.3 -0.29,.48 -0.59,.68 -0.2,.2 -0.51,.31 -0.81,.31 -0.3,0 -0.58,-0.10 -0.68,-0.40 -0.1,-0.3 -0.18,-0.70 -0.18,-1.40 l 0,-10.99 -3.40,0 0,11.21 c 0,1.4 .18,2.39 .68,3.09 .49,.7 1.21,1 2.21,1 1.4,0 2.48,-0.69 3.18,-2.09 l .09,0 .31,1.78 2.59,0 0,-14.99 c 0,0 -3.40,.00 -3.40,-0.09 z m 17.31,0 0,11.90 c -0.1,.3 -0.29,.48 -0.59,.68 -0.2,.2 -0.51,.31 -0.81,.31 -0.3,0 -0.58,-0.10 -0.68,-0.40 -0.1,-0.3 -0.21,-0.70 -0.21,-1.40 l 0,-10.99 -3.40,0 0,11.21 c 0,1.4 .21,2.39 .71,3.09 .5,.7 1.18,1 2.18,1 1.39,0 2.51,-0.69 3.21,-2.09 l .09,0 .28,1.78 2.62,0 0,-14.99 c 0,0 -3.40,.00 -3.40,-0.09 z m 20.90,2.09 c .4,0 .58,.11 .78,.31 .2,.3 .30,.59 .40,1.09 .1,.5 .09,1.21 .09,2.21 l 0,1.09 -2.5,0 0,-1.09 c 0,-1 -0.00,-1.71 .09,-2.21 0,-0.4 .11,-0.8 .31,-1 .2,-0.3 .51,-0.40 .81,-0.40 z m -50.49,.12 c .5,0 .8,.18 1,.68 .19,.5 .28,1.30 .28,2.40 l 0,4.68 c 0,1.1 -0.08,1.90 -0.28,2.40 -0.2,.5 -0.5,.68 -1,.68 -0.5,0 -0.79,-0.18 -0.99,-0.68 -0.2,-0.5 -0.31,-1.30 -0.31,-2.40 l 0,-4.68 c 0,-1.1 .11,-1.90 .31,-2.40 .2,-0.5 .49,-0.68 .99,-0.68 z m 39.68,.09 c .3,0 .61,.10 .81,.40 .2,.3 .27,.67 .37,1.37 .1,.6 .12,1.51 .12,2.71 l .09,1.90 c 0,1.1 .00,1.99 -0.09,2.59 -0.1,.6 -0.19,1.08 -0.49,1.28 -0.2,.3 -0.50,.40 -0.90,.40 -0.3,0 -0.51,-0.08 -0.81,-0.18 -0.2,-0.1 -0.39,-0.29 -0.59,-0.59 l 0,-8.5 c .1,-0.4 .29,-0.7 .59,-1 .3,-0.3 .60,-0.40 .90,-0.40 z" id="ytp-id-30">
        </path>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Simplemente con añadirle un `display: none;` a `class="ytp-impression-link"`, el elemento se oculta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Claro, esto desde la consola; he intentado añadir esta regla CSS a mi hoja de estilos para hacerla permanente y para todos los vídeos de mi web:

```
.ytp-impression-link {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Pero no parece funcionar; ¿sabéis si es posible invalidar estas directivas CSS de YouTube de alguna manera?

Comment: ¿Y que estilos se aplican por defecto?
¿Has probado a aumentar la especificidad del selector?

Comment: ¿Cómo incluyes el video en tu página? Si es a través de un `iframe`, no puedes afectar sus estilos.

Comment: Sí, mediante un `iframe`; ¿hay otra manera?